# Queue in producer side

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

In want to use RabbitMQ to send events to a server from a mobile C# app. The user records a lot of events in the whole day (number of products manufactured, consumed water, ...) and they need to be delivered in a server to be processed. I understand that RabbitMQ creates a queue in the server but also, I would like to have a queue en in client side, in the mobile app. It is usual that in some parts of the factory Internet fails, so when the user records any event, it needs to be sent using the RabbitMQ client, but if Internet fails, it should remain in an "internal" queue, waiting to be sent in the next synchronization. 
Which is the best approach for this problem?  Does have RabbitMQ client library a feature for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No RabbitMQ does not provide any such thing , typically for a user case like your it is best to use a local light weight database. You can go for something like SQLite.

Keep the data locally till it is synchronized and once done you may delete it from local.